# What is better for mobility limited on Spirit: nonstop or big front seat?

Tags: usa, air-travel, accessibility, spirit-airlines

I have mobility limitations.  I cannot stand for more than a few seconds. I can walk like a normal person but only for a limited range of 100-300' (30-100m) before having to stop, and stopping requires sitting down.  Upside, 8000' pressure altitude won't be a problem.

I'm locked into Spirit (USA internal flight) because they are the only sanely priced option given my last minute booking.  I'm familiar with Spirit and their big front seat.  Baggagewise I know their tricks and will take only a small under-seat carry-on.  The rest goes UPS. I'm in no fit shape to lug baggage through airports.

One option I can book is a nonstop. No deplaning and replaning, but The Big Seats are not available and I have to sit in cramped mid-plane seats, and more worrisome, on exit, there will be lots of painful standing around  while people queuing up in the aisles and shove back and forth trying to get their bags out of the overheads.

The other option is a one-stop, which means shuffling off the airplane at the layover, because Spirit wants the plane totally emptied, even though you have a ticket in the same seat for the onward segment.  But it's reasonably direct, and the Big Front Seats are available on both segments, which means I directly walk off the plane With almost no wait.

My puzzler is this:

What will be the most achievable option and what am I overlooking? Are there resources or opportunities I am missing? (First time traveling with an impairment.)

Related, will it be worth paying $5 for "shortcut" expedited TSA line, or does everyone do that, defeating the point?

Comment: Have you considered requesting wheelchair service?  I realize you can move without it, but it might be the best way to guarantee that you don't have to stand.

Comment: Also, if you have a disability, you ought to be eligible to preboard, which removes the element of standing around in the aisle.

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't know that was a thing. Can you describe how that works? Where do they meet you? Does it help through TSA?

Comment: I don't have any direct experience, but certainly people in wheelchairs pushed by airport employees are a common sight in airports, and there's a "wheelchair service" option in Spirit's booking.  Maybe you'd like to ask a separate question about this specifically.

Comment: There's a little bit of information at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/120503/1362, but it sounds like you'd want more details.

Comment: Are there window seats left on the nonstop flight? Are they an option for you? Because when sitting in a window seat, upon exit, you don't need to stand up before the plane is reasonably empty and then just walk off.

Answer (score 7):

I think there is one option you are overlooking.

When you have a disability, you are entitled to use services for people with disabilities.

You can add **Wheelchair service** to your flight by by going to their homepage, www.spirit.com, click on My Trips, and edit your information, or contact Spirit Airlines Reservations at 801.401.2222.

Even though this information will be added to your reservation in advance, please let a team member know of what you need when arriving to their station and at your destination. Assistance will be provided once it’s requested to one of their team members.

Important to know is that Spirit will NEVER charge you anything regarding your disability. The wheelchair assistance is for free.